# How can you change the default Closure resolve strategy for a Groovy script?

Tags: groovy, scope, closures

I'm writing a large Groovy script containing a number of global properties and Closures. All of the Closures are being used to add new methods to existing classes, e.g.:

```
myProperty = 'foo'
// ...more script code...

class MyClass {
    def myProperty = 'default'
}
// ...more script code...

MyClass.metaClass.evaluate = { ->
    myProperty = 'bar'
}

def mc = new MyClass()
mc.evaluate()
println mc.myProperty // prints out "default" instead of "bar"
```

My intention is for the Closure's `myProperty` to refer to the delegate class' `myProperty` rather than the global one. I've found a couple of ways to deal with this:

1) Explicitly dereference `delegate` within the closure:

```
MyClass.metaClass.evaluate = { ->
    delegate.myProperty = 'bar'
}

def mc = new MyClass()
mc.evaluate()
println mc.myProperty // prints out "bar" as desired
```

2) Set the resolve strategy of the closure to DELEGATE_ONLY:

```
def evalClosure = { ->
    myProperty = 'bar'
}
evalClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
MyClass.metaClass.evaluate = evalClosure

def mc = new MyClass()
mc.evaluate()
println mc.myProperty // prints out "bar" as desired
```

I would prefer to use approach #2 to avoid having "delegate" all over the place within my closures, but I'm not fond of having to set the resolve strategy for each and every closure I create.

**How do I tell Groovy to use a DELEGATE_ONLY resolve strategy for all Closures by default? Is this even possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way I know of to change the default delegation strategy, as far as I can see you have 2 options:

1. Split your script into classes (so you don't have the script level `myProperty` and the class level `myProperty` in the same scope)
2. Write a method to change the `resolveStrategy` and call this when you set your `metaClass`, ie:

   ```
   def only( Closure c ) {
     c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
     c
   }

   MyClass.metaClass.evaluate = only { ->
       myProperty = 'bar'
   }
   ```

Comment: LOL. I had the second approach as an answer yesterday but did not provide, thinking that OP would say "anyways I have to use `only()` per closure, I would rather use `closure.resolveStrategy`". I also tried using `@Category`, inheritance etc but I always got the default `resolveStrategy`. Then I convinced myself, I have to wait for @tim_yates to enlighten us. :-)

Comment: @dmahapatro hehe, you should trust your instincts more ;-) I feel BDKosher is going to dislike the answer, but I can't think of any other way to do it (it's not an option for the CompilerConfiguration class either)

Comment: Exactly. I was also thinking if `ClosureMetaClass` would help but as you said it wont. That was a good brain exercise for me for few hours. :-)

Comment: Option #2 looks like the best that can be done for the time being. Thanks for the idea (from both of you). I'll mark this as the correct answer (until, perhaps, future versions of Groovy allow for this to be configurable).